# Insufficient privilege in oracle

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, privileges

I have two schema called master and transaction.

In master one table called -  `BCC_TM_CITY`

In transaction one procedure called `PR_GETCITIES`.

In this procedure table `BCC_TM_CITY` used like this

```
select * from master.BCC_TM_CITY;
```

My problem is, recently I dropped the table and added again in master. After that, in `PR_GETCITIES` procedure, the place referring table (`BCC_TM_CITY`) am getting error ( Insufficient privilege ). Now I want to know how to give privilege to this table in SQL developer and want to solve this error.

Please any help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Sure it is `mater.BCC_TM_CITY` and not `master.BCC_TM_CITY`? An **s** is missing, I guess it's a typo and edited it.

Comment: No problem. Anyway, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **GRANT** the required privileges on the table to the user.

For example, if you want to grant **SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE** privileges, you would run the following GRANT statement:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON BCC_TM_CITY TO master;
```

If you want to grant only SELECT access on the table, but to all the users, you could grant the privileges to the public keyword. For example:

```
GRANT SELECT ON BCC_TM_CITY TO public;
```

See more examples and usage [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/grant_revoke.php).